Can I lubricate a gas valve?
I have a freestanding outdoor patio heater which is powered by a propane tank. The heater has a control knob that controls gas flow to the burner for high/low/off etc. (separate from the knob on the tank itself)
From being outside uncovered the heaters knob has become difficult to turn.
Using a pair of pliers I was able to open and close the knob a few times to get it unstuck but it's still difficult to twist by hand.
Can I spray it with penetrating oil or something similar? How can I loosen the knob?

try silicone grease

How do I get silicone grease into the knob mechanism?

the corrosion friction builds from outside

You could spray the valve exterior with a silicone lube.  SiliKroil, maybe?
